# R plotly add_trace to a chart with color groups

Tags: r, plotly

For data set `mtcars`, I want to plot a scatter plot (`wt` v.s. `mpg`) with `am` as the color group.

Then I want to add a trace from (2,15) to (3,25).

```
mtcars$am = as.character(mtcars$am)
plot_ly(mtcars,x = ~ wt, y= ~ mpg, color = ~ am, type='scatter', mode = 'markers') %>% 
    add_trace(x = c(2,15), y = c(3,25), mode="lines")
```

The code without `add_trace` works fine. How to add this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = wt, y =  mpg, col = am)) + geom_segment(aes(x = 2, y = 3, xend = 15, yend = 25))
ggplotly(p)
```

Option 2:

```
plot_ly() %>% 
add_trace(data = mtcars,x = ~ wt, y= ~ mpg, color = ~ am, type='scatter', mode = 'markers') %>%
add_trace( x = c(2,15, rep(NA,nrow(mtcars))), y = c(3,25,rep(NA,nrow(mtcars))), mode="lines")
```

[image]

Comment: Any way to use `plot_ly` directly? I have timestamps in my data. Plotly is more timestamp friendly.

Comment: In the option 2, there is no color. That's the difficult point. Removing `rep` doesn't change anything if we don't need `am` for color.